# Function in an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

JS-folks,
I've got a problem with a little test-script.

I've got this JS:

```
var button = {
    lastClick: 0,
    nowTime: new Date().getTime(),
    go: function () {
        var diff = this.nowTime - this.lastClick; 
        if (diff < 3000) alert('Too fast:' + diff / 1000); 
        lastClick = this.nowTime;
    }.bind(this)
};
```

And this HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Go"  onClick="button.go();" />
```

The `go`-function should use the `nowTime` and `lastClick` values from my `button`-object but they are *undefined*. Can anybody help me?

[JS-Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8u4Du/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `this` is undefined when you make the binding (so you're binding to `window`).

You can do this :

```
var button = {
    lastClick: 0,
    nowTime: new Date().getTime()
};
button.go = function () {
    var diff = this.nowTime - this.lastClick; 
    if (diff < 3000) alert('Too fast:' + diff / 1000); 
    this.lastClick = this.nowTime;
}.bind(button);
```

You were also missing a `this.` before `lastClick`.

An alternative is to use a closure/factory :

```
var button = (function(){
  var lastClick = 0;
  var nowTime = new Date().getTime();
  return {
    go: function () {
      var diff = nowTime - lastClick; 
      if (diff < 3000) alert('Too fast:' + diff / 1000); 
      lastClick = nowTime;
    }
  }
})();
```

A difference (which may or not be a benefit for you) is that the internal state of the button is hidden in this version (the fields are usually said to be "private").

If you want nowTime to always be the current time, don't store it :

```
var button = (function(){
  var lastClick = 0;
  return {
    go: function () {
      var nowTime = new Date().getTime();
      var diff = nowTime - lastClick; 
      if (diff < 3000) alert('Too fast:' + diff / 1000); 
      lastClick = nowTime;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: It's not necessary to separate the definitions of `button` and `button.go`, is it? Also, `bind` isn't necessary as well here. I wonder if alexP isn't referring to something else with that `this` as the argument of `bind`.

Comment: @MaxArt bind is necessary if you want to do, for example `setTimeout(button.go, 100);`.

Comment: Seems to work but now `lastClick` is equal to `nowTime` on every click. But `nowTime` should use `getTime()` http://fiddle.jshell.net/8u4Du/5/

Comment: @alexP You want nowTime to always be new Date().getTime() ? So why store it ?

Comment: Good question @dystroy :-) I'll use your last suggestion. Thanks a lot.